# Win7 widget: RSS/Feed Headlines has stop symbol when hovering

Tags: windows-7, rss, desktop-gadget

[image: Hand link icon with stop]

As you can see from the picture I get a stop symbol (PrtScn doesn't capture cursor, so I edited that in) & no images load. This happens on multiple different feeds, so I have trouble believing that's the cause, as it happens with the default-included feeds as well. Things I have tried without sucess:

- Disabled all firewall+AV's
- Restart
- Run sidebar.exe as Admin

Not sure what is causing this, maybe the microsoft [recent article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/advisory/2719662) saying widgets are a security concern & how to disable ([as well as their site deactivation for additional widgets](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/personalize/gadgets))

Comment: I actually don't see the stop symbol in the screenshot.  Have you confirmed the RSS Feed work with some other RSS client?

Comment: Its the link (hand) icon, with a stop symbol to the right of it (its shaded white with a black border). The RSS feed opens (as seen in the screenshot), is up-to-date, & the 'Read online...' link works to open it in a browser. Just odd the cursor & that pictures don't load. I only have one other win7 PC available to me, I will be attempting to try it later today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derp. Internet Explorer being offline causes this. I had gone offline to check a .mht file I had created worked successfully. I noticed after I opened internet explorer to click a link & it had the same icon

Once again: IE being offline is the cause, it now is working. Hopefully this helps someone else who gunks things up